# .net Core 3.1 return empty JObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I faced a strange problem. I create Web API functionality and when I return answer of my DTO class with JObject member I get empty array in Postman.
Code:

**DTO:**

```
public class EntityAttributesDTO
{
    public JObject Json { get; set; }
}
```

**FarmController:**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("entities")]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetEntitiesAsync()
{
    return await Mediator.Send(new AttributesHandler.Query { });
}
```

**AttributesHandler:**

```
   public async Task<List<EntityAttributesDTO>> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        List<EntityAttributesDTO> returnAttributes = new List<EntityAttributesDTO>();
        string str = @"{ ""context_name"": { ""lower_bound"": ""value"", ""upper_bound"": ""value"" } }";

         returnAttributes.Add(
              new EntityAttributesDTO
              {
                   Json = JObject.Parse((string)str);
              }
         );

        return returnAttributes;
    }
```

But in Postman I get empty JSON, only brackets. Possibly something change in core 3.1, i don't get it. How can I solve my problem? I need to transform a string to JSON format. But the table only has **id, parentid, type, value**. That is, recursion. The number of properties is dynamic.

Comment: I don't understand why you are returning raw JSON, as opposed to a proper entity that gets serialised to JSON.

Comment: just dummy, for test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked in my side, you may compare yours with it. And pls allow me to post as answer so that I can show it clearly. And certainly, if I misunderstood in some place pls kindly add more details so that we may locate the issue by them.

I newly created an asp.net core 3.1 MVC project and this is my controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HelloController : Controller
    {
        public JsonResult Index()
        {
            string str3 = @"{ ""context_name"": { ""lower_bound"": ""value"", ""upper_bound"": ""value"" } }";
            List<EntityAttributesDTO> list = new List<EntityAttributesDTO>();
            list.Add(new EntityAttributesDTO { Json = JObject.Parse(str3) });
            return Json(list);
        }
    }
}
```

My ConfigureServices methon in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        }
```

And don't forget to add nuget package:

[image]

And this is test result.

[image]